# How to configure MessageDispatcherServlet programmatically

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets

I am trying to learn spring-ws and started with this tutorial:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/#initial.

What I would like to do now is to start the service on non-embedded servlet container by configuring the application programmatically.

I am stuck on how to setup Message Dispatcher Servlet without web.xml. What i tried to is to 
implement WebApplicationInitializer interface's method onStartup(ServletContext servletContext).

```
public class ServerInitializer  implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(WebServiceConfig.class.getName());
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);


        // Create dispatcher for named context
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcherServlet = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet", servlet);

        // Load on startup
        dispatcherServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        // Add URL mapping for dispatcher
        dispatcherServlet.addMapping("/*");


    }

}
```

However, when i deploy this to tomcat, requests i send with SOAP UI( which are working on tutorial sample) are never getting mapped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i got it to work in the end:

```
public class WebServiceInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String ACTIVE_PROFILE = "production";

    /**
     * Registers and loads on startup MessageDispatcherServlet for the SOAP messages
     */
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        // @EnableWs, @Configuration, @ComponentScan
        context.setConfigLocation(WebServiceBeans.class.getName());
        context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles(ACTIVE_PROFILE);

        // use MessageDispatcherServlet instead of standard DispatcherServlet for SOAP messages
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setContextClass(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class);
        servlet.setApplicationContext(context);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);

        // register MessageDispatcherServlet as Web Service entry point
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("MessageDispatcherServlet",
                servlet);

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }
```

**Edit:**// Added proper way to do this, previous answer had a lot of redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

Extend AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer and implement 3 remaining methods
+ add your own servlet inside onStartup

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/*" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { RootContextConfiguration.class, SecurityConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("someotherServlet",
                new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/*");
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried this with no success. For RootContextConfiguration i have provided WebServiceConfig class - like one from tutorial but without ServletRegistrationBean. For servletConfigClasses i have set CountryEndpoint - im guessing this is wrong ?

Comment: Missing context declaration, should it be:   AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext(); ?

Comment: Should i register DispatcherServlet or MessageDispatcherServlet ? I am getting error: no mapping found for http request with DispatcherServlet as you suggested