# ServletRegistrationBean doesn't works for the multiple URL mapping paths

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I was developing code looking at https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-soap-webservice-example/, In the below bean I want to allow request to be executed for `/*` and `/service/*`, so I changed to

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/service/*");
}
```

To

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext){
    MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
    servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/*","/service/*");
}
```

Below configurations doesn't works when we execute the `/service/*` url. How can we fixed this ?

Comment: Have you tried putting the more specific url mapping first? I won't be much help since I haven't done much with SOAP in a very very long time.

Comment: Yes, I already tried more specific first then then more generic, but it did not worked. Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: Can you change `/*` with `/**` and also make sure `wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri` is correctly used according to endpoint and have a try again

Comment: see if answer helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464931/how-to-configure-messagedispatcherservlet-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping works for me. I downloaded the example and made changes as per your question.

I see the mappings registered(log) and the wsdl(browser) loaded as shown in the screenshot.

> `Mapping servlet: 'messageDispatcherServlet' to [/*, /service/*]`

Spring Boot Log, WSDL
 [image: Startup log and wsdl]
Soap Request Response

[image: Soap Request Response]

Not sure what's not working for you. "Below configurations doesn't works when we execute the /service/* url."